# Do screw on antennae actually do anything?

Tags: antenna

I'm not posting this on drone SE because I think this has more to do with electrical stuff than flying drones.

---

I've been flying my drone around a bit, and most of the time I screw on an antenna. The picture is always clear, or as clear as it normally is, and everything looks fine with the antenna. Then one day I realized that I hadn't even put on the antenna and the picture had been the exact same. I thought maybe I was just not remembering differently, but when I watched the video while removing/adding the antenna, the quality was still the same. This made me wonder,

Do screw on antennae actually do anything?

Comment: Is it possible that the signal can go farther with the antenna?

Comment: @user253751, maybe, not sure. I had the drone out as far as I would normally go and the quality still seemed the same. I can't really go to far because there's a road on one side and houses on the other and the drone is kinda expensive.

Comment: Out in the countryside where it wasn't possibly getting interfered with by other sources?

Comment: @Andyaka, no i fly pretty close to town right off the highway.

Comment: It depends entirely on the design of your drone. The radio system on the drone may well just be poorly designed or built causing the antenna to not provide any improvement. Or just as likely is that the antenna is improving the reception but you are just unable to detect the difference. All that said I also just want to point out that if I was designing a drone I would certainly also sell an optional screw on antenna even if i knew it didnt provide any improvements, just because gullable people with enough money will choose to buy it anyway and will convince themselves that it improved it.

Answer (score 2):

If your drone has analog imaging, then with more that 30 dB SNR, you will not see any improvement in the reception.

The frame and line sync are much more robust (much further distance) than the pixels.
Thus even for very weak video, with lots of snow (black/white pixels), your image will still be stable on the display.